# Sending email with SSL in VB6

Tags: email, ssl, vb6

How to send emails in Visual Basic 6 with SSL option enabled?

Comment: what library are you using to send emails without SSL?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [webdav](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebDAV) protocol to send the email via an IXMLHTTPRequest. An example showing how to do this can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms878112%28v=exchg.65%29.aspx).

To send via a server that has an SSL certificate just remember to include the https:// at the beginning of the URL.